# append js, как добавить span к элементам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таймер обратного отсчета. Сейчас он работает, но выводит цифры в одном блоке, нужно что бы выводил каждую цифру отдельным блоком для оформления. Пробовал через append но получается какой то цикл...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var banner = $("#banner-message").find('.timer');

  var timerId = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var d = now.getDay();
    var h = 24 - now.getHours();
    var m = 60 - now.getMinutes();
    var s = 60 - now.getSeconds();
    banner.text(d + ' : ' + h + ' : ' + m + " : " + s);

    if(d == 0 && h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0){
           document.location.reload();
    }

  }, 1000);

});
```

Вот так пробовал: `banner.append('<span>' + d + '</span>' '<span>' + h + '</span>' '<span>' + m + '</span>''<span>' + s + '</span>');` но консоль показывает что синтаксическая ошибка... Заранее спасибо за ответы

Comment: Строки приклеивают через `+` ... `'</span>' + '<span>'` или сразу `'</span><span>'` И вместо append нужен `.html( ... )`

Comment: Спасибо большое, как я не подумал о .html() сам не знаю....

Answer (score 1):

> `... + '</span>' '<span>' + ...`

Оператор конкатенации пропущен в этих местах выражения (между двумя строковыми литералами).

---

Как это делается на самом деле:

```js
// это нужно только для показа результата в сниппете
const banner = $('#test'),
      [d, h, m, s] = 'DD,HH,MM,SS'.split(',');

// а это суть решения
banner.append($(
  [d, h, m, s].map(v => `<span>${v}</span>`).join('')
));
```

```css
#test span { display: inline-block; padding: 0 0.5em; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Ну и на ванильном JS, без ненужной сегодня jQuery - будет почти то же самое:

```js
const banner = document.querySelector('#test'),
      [d, h, m, s] = 'DD,HH,MM,SS'.split(',');
banner.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
  [d, h, m, s].map(v => `<span>${v}</span>`).join('')
);
```

```css
#test span { display: inline-block; padding: 0 0.5em; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```